# ImportError: libpython3.7m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I am having trouble running a python script on a computing cluster and I apologize ahead of time if this is a naive mistake. I'm not sure if the problem originates from me configuring my own conda virtual environment incorrectly but the problem nonetheless is reproduced when I run:

```
srun -p use-everything --pty python test.py
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from acme.agents.tf import dqn
  File "/om2/user/armas/anaconda/envs/dist_rl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/acme/agents/tf/dqn/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from acme.agents.tf.dqn.agent import DQN
  File "/om2/user/armas/anaconda/envs/dist_rl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/acme/agents/tf/dqn/agent.py", line 20, in <module>
    from acme import datasets
  File "/om2/user/armas/anaconda/envs/dist_rl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/acme/datasets/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from acme.datasets.reverb import make_reverb_dataset
  File "/om2/user/armas/anaconda/envs/dist_rl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/acme/datasets/reverb.py", line 22, in <module>
    from acme.adders import reverb as adders
  File "/om2/user/armas/anaconda/envs/dist_rl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/acme/adders/reverb/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from acme.adders.reverb.base import DEFAULT_PRIORITY_TABLE
  File "/om2/user/armas/anaconda/envs/dist_rl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/acme/adders/reverb/base.py", line 26, in <module>
    import reverb
  File "/om2/user/armas/anaconda/envs/dist_rl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/reverb/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from reverb import item_selectors as selectors
  File "/om2/user/armas/anaconda/envs/dist_rl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/reverb/item_selectors.py", line 19, in <module>
    from reverb import pybind
  File "/om2/user/armas/anaconda/envs/dist_rl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/reverb/pybind.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as _tf; from .libpybind import *; del _tf
ImportError: libpython3.7m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
srun: error: node014: task 0: Exited with exit code 1
```

On my local machine, I was struggling with same issue when I was running a virtual environment, I solved this problem simply with `sudo apt-get install libpython3.7`.

Here's some other things that may be helpful to know.

```
$which libpython
/usr/bin/which: no libpython in (/om2/user/armas/anaconda/envs/dist_rl/bin:/om2/user/armas/anaconda/bin:/om2/user/armas/anaconda/condabin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin)
```

```
$echo $PATH
/om2/user/armas/anaconda/envs/dist_rl/bin:/om2/user/armas/anaconda/bin:/om2/user/armas/anaconda/condabin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

```
$echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/om2/user/armas/anaconda/bin/
```

When I change my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, i.e. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/om2/user/armas/anaconda/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and run the script, my anaconda thinks I do not have jax installed. I ran pip install dm-acme[jax] and now when I run the script, it was saying I don't have a module named atari_py. I think it is leading me down a chain of dependencies.

I had installed acme using [this link](http://%20https://github.com/deepmind/acme), but using a conda environment. My system admin said it could possibly be that acme is not made for anaconda. Why could that be if that is the case?

If there's anything I missed please let me know and I'll be sure to add, thank you again!

Comment: Two things that could be helpful (1) could you give us the full error traceback of the `ImportError` line (2) can you give us some idea what kind of code is run in test.py? To me it looks a bit like an extension module that was compiled in a different environment and now executed in a wrong environment. As a side note: there are a couple of things that are strange in your diagnostics: `which libpython` won't work - `which` will only find executables not libraries. `$echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should print the path to a library directory (e.g. `/om2/user/armas/anaconda/lib`) not `bin`.

Comment: Hello, I have since updated the post. Let me know what you think thanks!

Comment: I also had this issue with using dearpygui in a virtual environment and this solution worked. I had to run apt-get from within the virtual environment in the CMD prompt to install the required library.

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libpython3.7
```